# What happens when exceeding Firebase Auth API quota

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, quota

I know about the Auth API quotas from [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits). 
And I want to know what happens when these quotas are exceeded?
Do I get charged more money?
Or does the Auth functionality stop until the limit is over?

Answer (score 1):

In `Firebase`, if you use the "Free" or "Spark" plan, if you exceed any quota **(Not only Auth)**, the functionality will not work until the limit is over. But if you use the "Pay As You Go" plan, you will get charged more money.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ameer Taweel. Can you tell me in case of "Pay As You Go" plan, what is the extra charge for each request?

Comment: You can check this page for all the info you need about Firebase pricing:
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/